# Where to put xml parsing method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method that parses an xml document. I assume this method should be in the model, as it uses model data to parse the xml. Can you confirm that the best place to put all data manipulation methods is in the model?

If they are in the model, can they still be used from the controller, or should all data submitted from all forms, if there is manipulation, be done in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To what extent is the parsing linked with the model?

- If they are really tied, the parsing should belong to the model, unless it's too big and it would be better to create it in it's own module (or class) and include it in the model
- If the parser just needs some arguments from the model, it could simply be a module or class in your `/lib` directory

Whatever you choose, the controller would access it easily.

Sidenote: be sure to include the lib directory in your loadpath

Comment: The idea was to take the xml file from a user that browses to it on their hard drive, parses then inserts 8 xml fields into 8 fields of the model.